# Spring Data JPA – @Query – Not supported for DML operations

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using

- Spring 4.3.9.RELEASE,
- Hibernate 3.6.3.Final,
- Spring Data JPA 1.6.4.RELEASE

for exposing Rest services. 
I am using `@Transactional` and `@Modifying` for one of the update queries. Still, I am getting the error `Spring Data JPA – @Query – Not supported for DML operations`. 
Any idea why I am not able to execute the DML operations although the configurations are correct. 
I can use the CRUD operations save, delete as expected. 
I have provided the transaction manager configuration below.

```
<bean id="jpaTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="jpaEntityManagerFactory" />
    <qualifier value="jpaTxManager"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jpaTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
```

---

### Method declaration:

```
@Modifying 
@Query("UPDATE MyFavTable mf SET mf.defaultList = 'N' WHERE mf.key= :contackey") 
List<MyFavTable> updateMyTable(@Param("contackey") Long contackey);
```

---

### Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.hql.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for DML operations [UPDATE com.cat.solar.hibernate.model.MyFavTable mfo SET mfo.defaultList = 'N' WHERE mfo.contackey = :contackey]; nested
exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for
        DML operations [UPDATE com.cat.solar.hibernate.model.MyFavTable mfo
        SET mfo.defaultList = 'N' WHERE mfo.contackey = :contackey]     
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:293)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:108)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:403)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy63.clearUpListDefault(Unknown Source)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.clearUpListDefault(Unknown Source)    
    at com.cat.solar.service.MyFavoritesOwnerService.saveUpdateFavoriteOwner(MyFavoritesOwnerService.java:271)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.saveUpdateFavoriteOwner(Unknown Source)   
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at com.cat.solar.logging.HijackAroundMethod.invoke(HijackAroundMethod.java:12)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73.saveUpdateFavoriteOwner(Unknown Source)   
    at com.cat.solar.service.EquipListServiceImpl.updateList(EquipListServiceImpl.java:433)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at com.cat.solar.logging.HijackAroundMethod.invoke(HijackAroundMethod.java:12)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.updateList(Unknown Source)    
    at com.cat.solar.controller.EquipmentsController.manageListUpdate(EquipmentsController.java:292)
    at com.cat.solar.controller.EquipmentsController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$457854e1.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.cat.solar.controller.EquipmentsController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ce2e1590.manageListUpdate(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:640)     
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)     
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:389)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.cat.solar.security.filter.XssFilter.doFilter(XssFilter.java:33)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.cat.solar.security.filter.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at cat.cis.tuf.server.filter.TUFExtendedFilterChainImpl.doFilter(TUFExtendedFilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at cat.cis.tuf.server.directory.GroupModificationEventFilter.doFilter(GroupModificationEventFilter.java:35)
    at cat.cis.tuf.sys.server.filter.TUFFilterChainImpl.doFilter(TUFFilterChainImpl.java:44)
    at cat.cis.tuf.server.filter.TUFExtendedFilterChainImpl.doFilter(TUFExtendedFilterChainImpl.java:54)
    at cat.cis.tuf.server.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:67)
    at cat.cis.tuf.sys.server.filter.TUFFilterChainImpl.doFilter(TUFFilterChainImpl.java:44)
    at cat.cis.tuf.server.filter.TUFExtendedFilterChainImpl.doFilter(TUFExtendedFilterChainImpl.java:54)
    at cat.cis.tuf.server.security.cws.CWSSecurityTokenContextFilter.doFilter(CWSSecurityTokenContextFilter.java:68)
    at cat.cis.tuf.sys.server.filter.TUFFilterChainImpl.doFilter(TUFFilterChainImpl.java:44)
    at cat.cis.tuf.server.filter.TUFExtendedFilterChainImpl.doFilter(TUFExtendedFilterChainImpl.java:54)
    at cat.cis.tuf.server.logging.LoggingRequestIDFilter.doFilter(LoggingRequestIDFilter.java:35)
    at cat.cis.tuf.sys.server.filter.TUFFilterChainImpl.doFilter(TUFFilterChainImpl.java:44)
    at cat.cis.tuf.server.filter.TUFExtendedFilterChainImpl.doFilter(TUFExtendedFilterChainImpl.java:54)
    at cat.cis.tuf.server.filter.TUFMasterFilter.doFilter(TUFMasterFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:502)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.hql.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for
        DML operations [UPDATE com.cat.solar.hibernate.model.MyFavoritesOwner
        mfo SET mfo.defaultList = 'N' WHERE mfo.contackey = :contackey]     
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:249)    
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:81)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:384)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 123 more 
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.QueryExecutionRequestException: Not supported for
        DML operations [UPDATE com.cat.solar.hibernate.model.MyFavoritesOwner
        mfo SET mfo.defaultList = 'N' WHERE mfo.contackey = :contackey]     
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.errorIfDML(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:346)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)   
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)    
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:246)
```

Comment: can you post your code that contains @Query and @ Modifying ?

Comment: @Modifying
@Query("UPDATE MyFavTable mf SET mf.defaultList = 'N' WHERE mf.key= :contackey")
List<MyFavTable> updateMyTable(@Param("contackey") Long contackey);

Comment: can you try adding `@Transactional(readOnly=false)` on your `updateMyTable(..)` method ?

Comment: I have tried that too still no luck

Comment: post full stacktrace please

Comment: Updated stacktrace in the question as it is not allowing here

Comment: are you sure you have @Modifying? and also its the same query ? because from the stacktrace is see "mfo.contackey" instead of "mf.contackey" in the code you posted ? or you can make sure to build the project again and try ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. i had just renamed it to mf while posting the question

Comment: When adding information to a question please edit the question instead of adding it in the comments. And please format stack traces as code in order to maintain the formatting which is really important in order to read stack traces.

Answer (score 6):

Your method has a return type of `List<MyFavTable>`. 
Therefore Spring Data tries to invoke `QueryImpl.getResultList` which intern expects some kind of select-statement.

Change your method to return void and it should work as expected.

Comment: Or you can change it to int and it will output the number of rows updated.