# Spring Data JPA update query (Not supported for DML operations)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm having problems executing an update query in springdatajpa. here is the code in the repository layer:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("update CustomerTransaction ct set ct.amountPayment =:trnAmount WHERE ct.loanAccount.id=:loanAccountId AND ct.paymentTerm=:paymentTerm")
List<CustomerTransaction> updateCurrentCustomerTransaction(@Param("loanAccountId") long loanAccountId, 
                                                            @Param("paymentTerm") int paymentTerm, 
                                                            @Param("trnAmount") BigDecimal trnAmount);
```

As you can see, I've already added the @Modifying annotation but it still throws an error of **"Not supported for DML operations"**
I am using Hibernate 5.4.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data JPA – @Query – Not supported for DML operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52031911/spring-data-jpa-query-not-supported-for-dml-operations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the return type of your method to `void` or `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The update SQL query usually return the count of updated rows, so you need to add int as return type if you want to capture that else you can use void